Outline of symbols \top, \bot, \vdash
In Nicolas Bourbaki's Algebra I, he uses an outline version of \top for his internal composition law (depicted below). Is there any way we can produce analogous symbols but with the vertical line "doubled" and "tripled" (see below). Similarly, can we produce a "doubled/tripled" \vdash and \vDash? Thanks! (I imagine we can rotate \top and variations to produce entailments, but I could be wrong.)


double is U+2AEA ⫪  \barV in unicode-math or stix2 for pdftex

U+2AE2 ⫢  U+2AEB ⫫

For entailment, the turnstile package offers at least double and (if I remember correctly) triple variants (horizontal/vertical etc.). It will not precisely match \vdash etc. Generally, users of turnstile need the symbols not to match \vdash and so on because the latter is not extensible. (It doesn't allow adding subscripts etc. in the way needed.) It's the only reasonable option for entailment symbols as far as I know. (I would be happy to be wrong.) I'm curious what they signify in algebra. Not the same as in logic, presumably?
